# Advanced set title icon

Tags: android, android-activity, bitmap, icons, title

How to set title icon of a activity from `android.graphics.Bitmap` object using system framework for java android application?

`((Activity)obj).getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.icon);`

This method not work with `android.graphics.Bitmap`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ActionBar#setIcon()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar#setIcon(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) requires a Drawable as you correctly mentioned. To wrap a Bitmap in a Drawable you have to use a [BitmapDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable).

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Bitmap bitmap = getBitmap(); // your Bitmap

    Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(mipmapDrawable);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

`Bitmap bitmap = _bitmap;`
`((Activity)obj).getActionBar().setIcon(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));`